# XSLT Transformation with match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml and I'm writing a XSLT to transform it:

```
<callop>
    <con>unit</con>
    <var>u</var>
    <var>v</var>
</callop>
```

The problem is that if `<callop>` is inside `<is>` then it should be a `<nano>` element and `<con>` becomes `<Fun>` but otherwise it's an `<Atom>` and `<con>` becomes a `<Rel>`.

How is this possible. Do I have to go and check what the parent node is?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this pretty easily by just specifying your templates with the full path. The more specific template match will take precedence, so there shouldn't be any issues.

```
<xsl:template match="is/callop">
   <nano>
     ...
...

<xsl:template match="callop">
   <Atom>
     ...
...
```

Comment: What about the '<con>' element inside '<callop>' what happens to that?

Comment: You can declare a separate template "is/callop/con" to match it and use apply-templates from the "is/callop" template, or just handle it inline, e.g.:

    <Fun><xsl:apply-templates select="con" /></Fun>